# Angular 9 Cordova App Hybrid Application and Lazy Loaded Modules

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, angular9, hybrid

I am working on an Angular9 Cordova application supposed to run only in IOS and in Android(no web).
I have several modules in the app. I am wondering, will there be any benefit if i make the module lazy loadable.

I know how the lazy loaded modules works in web , but not sure in the mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , I learned personally that there is great benefits in lazy loading even in Hybrid Applications.
Initially I was working only with Cordova and Angular.
Started seeing the load time improvements in the Application deployed in MobilePhones and Billboard devices with Lazy loading.
Also when I starred working in Ionic, by default the latest ionic comes with Lazy loading page concept.

Its best to use Angular Lazy loading in Cordova Applications.